# .htaccess with multi domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and right now I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is right now if I type www.domain1.com its return to domain1.com and not www.domain2.com

I will have it to if I type www.domain1.com, domain1.com or domain3.com its will return to this domain ( www.domain2.com ) and if i type ( domain2.com ) its return to www.domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

You just need this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request to a host that’s not *example.com* to *example.com*.